# understanding different character encodings

Tags: encoding, utf-8

When I save a text document in UTF-8 that's basically saying: Computer, use the codepage for UTF8 that's installed somewhere on your computer to figure out, how to turn the 1's and 0's to characters, right?

When I save this content:

```
激光
äüß
#§
```

in ISO-8895-1, it becomes this (on Linux, using Kate editor):

```
æ¿å
Ã¤Ã¼Ã
#Â§
```

What is not displayed here is that in the first and second row that are some weird squares displayed instead of characters (can be seen in developer tools).

So my understanding is that this means that the combination of 0's and 1's that represent 激 in utf-8 is mapped to æ in ISO-8895-1, right? And  the weird squares >  < happen because there is no mapping for that binary number in the ISO-8895-1 character set so the computer defaults to some other encoding.

Is that correct?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks, I had already read that, but I still wasn't 100% sure I had gotten it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of correct.
If you store a file as UTF-8, it usually gets a special byte combination that indicates its type of encoding at the beginning of the file. I think, Kate (don't know this editor) doesn't recognize this and just displays the file as something else. So basically, your file is still correct, but was just visualized in a wrong way.
The weird squares are another indicator, that Kate doesn't recognize those leading bytes, cause usually editors hide them from the user and just use the information to display the file correctly.

Comment: The BOM is discouraged in combination with UTF-8, so having a BOM is not usual for UTF-8 text

Answer (score 0):

You have it pretty much right. [The character U+6FC0 (激)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6fc0/index.htm) for example is encoded with 3 bytes in UTF-8: 0xE6 0xBF 0x80.

If you interpret these bytes in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), you get the characters `æ¿`. Depending on the version of ISO-8859-1, 0x80 is either not mapped to a character at all, or is mapped to a non-printable control character, that's why you can see only two characters for the three bytes.

If you use [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead of ISO-8859-1 you'll see `æ¿€`.